# checkPropTypes is not a function error while using with sveltekit

Tags: svelte, react-proptypes, sveltekit, sapper

I am using [prop-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types) npm package with sapper and It working fine but when I migrate to sveltekit it gives error.

`Command: npm run preview`

Uses eg:

```
import * as PropTypes from "prop-types";
const {checkPropTypes, number} = PropTypes;
   const propTypes = {
    threshold: number,
};
checkPropTypes(propTypes, $$props, "prop", "Observer");
```

Error:
`checkPropTypes is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

Putting the function inside `onMount` seems to work:

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import * as PropTypes from "prop-types";
    import { onMount } from "svelte";

    const { checkPropTypes, number } = PropTypes

    const propTypes = {
        threshold: number,
    };

    onMount(() => {
        checkPropTypes(propTypes, $$props, "prop", "Observer");
    })
</script>
```

However, from my testing, `npm run dev` works fine without changes, so it's strange that with `npm run preview` it breaks. For some reason, both `checkPropTypes` and `number` are undefined when using `preview`. What's weirder is that the module object looks like this:

```json
[Module: null prototype] {
  default: <ref *2> {
    array: <ref *1> [Function: shim] { isRequired: [Circular *1] },
    bigint: <ref *1> [Function: shim] { isRequired: [Circular *1] },
    bool: <ref *1> [Function: shim] { isRequired: [Circular *1] },
    func: <ref *1> [Function: shim] { isRequired: [Circular *1] },
    number: <ref *1> [Function: shim] { isRequired: [Circular *1] },
    object: <ref *1> [Function: shim] { isRequired: [Circular *1] },
    string: <ref *1> [Function: shim] { isRequired: [Circular *1] },
    symbol: <ref *1> [Function: shim] { isRequired: [Circular *1] },
    any: <ref *1> [Function: shim] { isRequired: [Circular *1] },
    arrayOf: [Function: getShim],
    element: <ref *1> [Function: shim] { isRequired: [Circular *1] },
    elementType: <ref *1> [Function: shim] { isRequired: [Circular *1] },
    instanceOf: [Function: getShim],
    node: <ref *1> [Function: shim] { isRequired: [Circular *1] },
    objectOf: [Function: getShim],
    oneOf: [Function: getShim],
    oneOfType: [Function: getShim],
    shape: [Function: getShim],
    exact: [Function: getShim],
    checkPropTypes: [Function: emptyFunctionWithReset] {
      resetWarningCache: [Function: emptyFunction]
    },
    resetWarningCache: [Function: emptyFunction],
    PropTypes: [Circular *2]
  }
}
```

So the function is there, it's just undefined. Again, it works correctly when using `build`. And there's a lot more weird behaviour if you experiment more, so maybe it's just a SvelteKit issue.

Anyways, you should simply use `onMount` for now to solve the issue.

---